# Does JSF1.2 has buit in CSRF protection?

Tags: security, jsf, csrf

I have tested a JSF application with the CSRFtester tool, and the tool didn't report any CSRF problems. But I had read in the "OWASP_Top_10_2007_for_JEE.pdf", that all Java EE web application frameworks are vulnerable to CSRF and also some says we need to create a secret key for each session and append it to the url. By doing this way we can secure our JSF application from the CSRF attack.This makes me confused. I cannot find any clear documentation. IS JSF is vulnerable to CSRF attack? What was the right way to protect a JSF application from CSRF attacks? Please help me out!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JSF is vulnerable to CSRF. I implemented CSRF prevention token for my JSF 1.2 application just a few days ago.

Here's what you could use:

[Tomcat CSRF Prevention Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter) (find the source)

[Another wonderful solution, can be easily implemented on JSF 1.2](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/02/preventing-csrf-with-jsf-20.html)

I used the combination of two. Works well.